# Can we remove the authentication from Alexa Voice Service by Amazon?

Tags: alexa-voice-service

I need to integrate Alexa Voice Service in my app. Currently Alexa ask for the Amazon login. Can we avoid these flow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, it is not possible to use AVS without exchanging authorization token. And for auth tokens it is necessary for the user to login via Amazon. As stated in the following documentation -:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-product-from-an-android-or-ios-mobile-app

So repeating what is given in the documentation, you can either pass on the auth token via your companion app of the device, iff the device does not have a GUI or ask for Amazon login in the mobile app, which is leveraging AVS.

Hope this helps.